# Entity framework - displaing related entities without include

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing code first EF6 application and I have one problem with including related entities.

I have model like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty(Order = 0)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
    public double? OldPrice { get; set; }
}
```

My Context has a DBSets like:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PromoCeny.Models.Product> Products { get; set; }

public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PromoCeny.Models.ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }

public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PromoCeny.Models.Shop> Shops { get; set; }
```

I was trying to access all `Product` objects like:

```
db.Products
```

And I'm getting list of `Products` but both properties `Shop` and `Category` are `null`

It's strange, but I have one working solution where something like this results proper object(with all properties set properly), but I cannot find difference between these projects.

I was trying to remove `virtual` flag from properties in model, but this doesn't work also.

Of course I can get list of Products like:

```
db.Products.Include(product => product.Shop).Include(product => product.Category)
```

But I would like to avoid that.

Do you know how to handle that?

**EDIT:**

I have just figured out that i had disabled lazy loading of Entities.

I have removed like:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

from Context and it's working right now.

Comment: I have figured it out. see my Edit

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to disabled lazy loading, this, as long as your relationships are defined correctly, should force linked properties to load I believe.

Comment: you mean I should add `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; ` to Context?

Comment: @Tomasz yes I believe that should force all layers to load.
This is a useful link [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: I thought you either use include to bring back related items in the initial query, or lazy loading to bring them back when you request the property. If LazyLoadingEnabled is false and without includes you won't get any related properties.

Comment: @Mant101 I think you have that backwards. Lazy loading means that it will only get the related property when you try to use it later, so you have to use `Include()` to ask for that property to be loaded ahead of time. With no lazy loading, it will get all related properties in the query, so there is no need for `Include()`.

Comment: @anaximander I've worked with every version of EF and at work our system has lazy loading disabled and I've never seen that behaviour. Include works the same with and without lazy loading enabled, and without any you just get the entity requested. You do get auto hookup so if another query brings back the related entity on the same context the navigation property will be populated

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes here; that's precisely what I'm describing. From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx): "Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed." That can't happen after the `DbContext` is disposed, so Include triggers "eager loading". From the same MSDN page: "Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query."

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're experiencing is caused by the lazy-load feature. This can be disabled in your context, like so:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public MyContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

Be aware that this turns off lazy loading for everything; if your object graph is highly interlinked your queries may get very slow as even simple queries can end up loading a lot of data.

Removing the `virtual` modifier from a collection property *should* disable lazy loading for that property, but you say it doesn't... To diagnose that, we'd need more info on your EF configuration.